# Is my malloc function allocating more than I intend to

Tags: c

Here is the code I'm trying to run. The `malloc` function allocates 800 bytes.

```
void DynamicMemoryAllocationUsingMalloc()
{
    int* p,i;
    if((p = (int*) malloc(800)) == NULL)
    {
        printf("\n Out of Memory \n");
        exit(0);
    }

    for(i =0;i < 800;i++)
    {
        printf(" 0x%x", (p + i));
        printf(" %d\n", *(p + i));

    }
}
```

But inside the for loop when I print the addresses I'm able to hop through 800 memory locations (using integer pointer `p`) each 4 byte long (size of an integer) safely which amounts to 3200 bytes. How is that possible or I'm being lucky not be getting access violation error even though I'm actually entering into a memory area which I've not yet allocated for my program? I see garbage being written in all the memory locations for the obvious reason as I've not set those memory location to anything.

**Note**: It is a C program being run on Windows 7.

Comment: Undefined behaviour is undefined.

Comment: Yes, you are being lucky. (or rather unlucky, as a segmentation fault is usually preferable to corrupt memory)

Comment: @KerrekSB I'm new to C world. May be I can't see the obvious. Can you please elaborate your comment.

Comment: @RBT: Evaluation of the expression `p + i` has undefined behaviour when the result is not within the allocated bounds, i.e. when `i` is greater than `800 / sizeof(int)`. That means the C language rules do not say *anything* about the behaviour of your program.

Comment: @KerrekSB   only in the language spec, every compiler has definite behavior of some sort that is worth knowing what it does in these kinds of cases

Comment: Who says that what you do is *safe*?  If you drive drunk you *might* still get home safely, but that doesn't mean that drunk driving is safe.

Comment: @KeithNicholas, no, compilers do not necessarily produce consistent manifestations of any particular form of undefined behavior.  Even if they did, it would not be worth knowing them because undefined behavior is to be avoided at all costs.

Comment: @KerrekSB: The UB does *not* start with `p + i`, since C *does* allow computing an address (just) beyond the bounds of an object. It's the dereference of a pointer pointing to such an address that is the first occurrence of undefined behavior in the program.

Comment: @KerrekSB so if I'm planning to store integers in the memory allocation I've done then I should actually write the for loop to hop through 200( 800/4) numbers only as the right measure. Had `p` been `char*` (which takes 1 byte) then this program is completely safe. Am I correct on this conclusion?

Comment: RBT, one thing you need to know about the C world is it is it's mostly pedantic and very language spec oriented.   You'll find under different language tags often more relaxed and helpful responses :)   but if you hit UB ( undefined behaviour) people will stop talking to you :)

Comment: RBT, Curious, why use `"%x"` instead of `"%p"` when printing a pointer?  Did not your compiler complain about the mis-match?  Was its warning levels well enabled?

Comment: @EOF: Hm, let's see: `p = malloc(n * sizeof(int))`, then `p + n` is one-past-the-end, yes? So "`i` greater than `n`" is not allowed (but "`i` equal to `n`" is).

Comment: @RBT: Yes, that's right. To allocate space for an array of `n` elements of type `T`, you need to call `malloc(n * sizeof(T))`. (And by definition, `sizeof(char)` is one.)

Comment: @KerrekSB Yes, but the program exhibits undefined behavior (by dereferencing a pointer pointing beyond the bounds of an object) *before* it exhibits undefined behavior due to pointer arithmetic not within the bounds of the object or one past the bounds.

Comment: @KerrekSB avoiding UB sure, but people hit it all the time and then have to debug it, and knowing what happens helps a lot,   if, like this OP, you think you will get an exception/crash of some sort, you may not realise your program can actually just work fine with UB ... until it doesn't, and then hard to know what to look for

Comment: @EOF: Ah yes, good point! (In that case, I just pointed out *one* part of the code that would cause UB :-) )

Comment: @KeithNicholas: Show those people ASAN and be done with it?

Comment: @chux It is a default C++ project template I'm using to write a C program with all the default settings. I've not changed anything anywhere. I'm writing this code in Visual Studio 2010. I'm not getting any warnings for using %x for printing memory addresses being pointed by the pointer.

Comment: @KerrekSB show the dude using windows? :)

Comment: @KeithNicholas: There's Clang for Windows now, isn't it?

Comment: Perhaps you were intending to malloc 800 * sizeof(int)? since you're stepping through it with an int*.

Comment: Personally, I think you were unlucky that the program didn't crash immediately on executing `*(p + i)` with `i == 200`.  Reading from memory that was not allocated for your use is undefined behaviour.  And undefined behaviour means anything can happen, including 'appearing to work as expected despite misplaced expectations' or 'crashing the program' or 'wrecking the system on which the program is running'.  Fortunately for you, the latter seldom happens.  Search for 'nasal demons' for more information.

Comment: Try running Release build!

Comment: @Ajay unfortunately it didn't crash even in release build :(. Looks like OS is being too kind to my process. BTW I'm currently running it on Windows Server 2008 R2 box. Windows 7 box was my home pc when I raised this post. UB has become way too deterministic in my case it seems.

Comment: @Ajay it works well in release mode even on my home pc which has Windows 7 Ultimate Service Pack 1

Answer (score 5):

> How is that possible or I'm being lucky not be getting access violation error even though I'm actually entering into a memory area which I've not yet allocated for my program?

When code reaches `printf(" %d\n", *(p + 200));` is is attempting to read outside allocated memory.  That is *undefined behavior*  UB.

UB is UB.  It may happen like this every day or change the next time you run.

---

You are not lucky.  Lucky would be for your code to stop right there.

Even reading uninitialized `int` data is UB. So code has UB (or maybe implementation defined) as soon as `printf(" %d\n", *(p + 0));`.  IAC, code could have stopped right there.

---

> Is my malloc function allocating more than I intend to?

That is the tricky bit.  Code that invokes UB creates questionable results.  Code without UB has no standard way to test the question.  The only non-UB way to determine this is if the library supplies a function with the answer.

```
printf("True size %lu\n", (unsigned long) True_size(p));
```

Note: OP asserts `int` is 4 bytes.

Comment: While this answer is correct, it does nothing to explain to OP why he is seeing this particular behaviour.

Comment: @jforberg  The behavior is not defined by the C spec.  We could make good guess or cast lots.  Aside from looking at OP's executable code, various answers would not be authoritative but opinions - maybe good or not.

Comment: The problem is that you're (plural) pretending like malloc is some arcane piece of mystery that we don't know anything about, when in fact it's well understood how malloc is usually implemented and it always involves allocating more memory than is immediately necessary. This could be an opportunity for OP to learn a bit more about how an OS works, instead we choose to just quote the standard and be done with it. "Don't ask, it's undefined behaviour".

Comment: And in no case is it necessary for anyone to guess or "draw lots". The code for malloc even on Windows is open source now, you can just have a look if you are wondering how it works.

Comment: @jforberg Hmmm, from someone who did not DV your answer, this answer seems to have attracted the Wrath of JF.  OTOH, your DV here was accompanied by comment - with although I disagree with - is welcomed.

Answer (score 5):

It's working probably because you're not reaching past the range of memory currently allocated for the process.  Modern systems typically allocate memory to a process in 4-kilobyte pages.  Your first allocation is possibly at the beginning of a page, and the memory you're snooping in is probably in the unallocated remainder of that first page.

The OS can't detect invalid memory accesses unless they go beyond the ranges of memory allocated for your process.  As far as the OS is concerned, it gave your process that page and the process is using it.  It doesn't care whether or not the malloc routine used by your process has said your program "owns" that memory yet.

It might be a fun experiment to see how far you can read before you get an access violation.  Just loop and print each address out before you try to read it.

Comment: So access violation happens only when I trip into another processes's memory space. Is it? What about the situation when this current loop trips into the memory space (belonging to my process space only) of another `malloc` operation which had happened in `main` before my current function `DynamicMemoryAllocationUsingMalloc` began executing?

Comment: I experimented it further on the maximum allowed loop counter to reach to the boundary condition. I am able to go till 3072. The moment I increase the maximum allowed loop counter to 3073, the program bursts with `access violation` error. I'm not sure if that gives a hint about OS's page size allocated to my process. 3072 counter value = 3072 * 4 (integer size) = 12288  bytes. This observation has been taken on a Windows 7 machine. Coincidentally, if I consider 4-kilobyte pages then 4-kilobyte * 3 also comes out to be 12288 bytes precisely. might be my process was allocated 3 pages by the OS.

Comment: Another process's memory space?  Sort of.  Each process has its own virtual memory space, and only certain ranges of that are valid, and access to an invalid address causes an error.  Your process just can't access the memory of another process.

Answer (score 2):

> But inside the for loop when I print the addresses I'm able to hop through 800 memory locations (using integer pointer p) each 4 byte long (size of an integer) safely which amounts to 3200 bytes.

Where I guess by "safely" you mean that the program does not crash.  This is an ok definition when applied to air travel, but not so appropriate for a computer program.

> How is that possible or I'm being lucky not be getting access violation error even though I'm actually entering into a memory area which I've not yet allocated for my program?

By accessing unallocated memory your program exhibits undefined behavior. You are to be commended for recognizing the problem.  To quote @KerrekSB, however, "Undefined behavior is undefined".  Generally speaking, you cannot assume any particular manifestation of undefined behavior.

If your program did happen to crash, with an access violation, for example, then you could be sure that it had exhibited undefined behavior, simply because C does not define any way to produce that behavior.  But just because it seems to do what you expect does not mean that its behavior is defined.  If it is not defined then, generally speaking, you cannot be confident that it will be consistent, either.

So basically, yes, you're just lucky.  Or maybe unlucky.  Myself, I'd rather have the program crash, so that I am alerted to the problem.

Answer (score 1):

This here be an example of undefined behavior.
Logically, this program should break. but it does not because the process image has some extra space that you can overflow into without having the operating system sending a segfault. I mean, instead of going to 800, go up to 1000, 10000, and so on. Eventually you'll get a segfault at some arbitrary number of iterations.

The reason you can go so high is because your program has a lot of overhead in the ram, this overhead is allowed to be overflowed into.

Answer (score -3):

**C standard answer**: Accessing memory beyond what you have allocated results in undefined behaviour.

**Real world answer**:Your program allocates memory using malloc() which provisions it from the operating system, in this case Windows. However, each malloc() call doesn't result in a call to the operating system. Malloc will in fact usually allocate a bit more memory than it needs right now and will then break off a chunk which is at least the size you requested. This is done for performance reasons since every call to the operating system has a bit of overhead. Also, there is a minimum "page size" which is the smallest unit of memory which can be allocated from the operating system. 4096 bytes is a typical page size.

So in your case, you are accessing the memory which malloc has provisioned from the system but has not allocated for use. You should avoid this since the next call to malloc might cause the memory to be allocated for another purpose.

Comment: Wow, not a popular answer it seems. Could one of the downvoters please explain where I'm wrong?

Comment: I'm not a downvoter. You're _not_ wrong, IMO, but you may need more detail. Things to consider: Does `malloc` use `sbrk` or `mmap` [modern ones use `mmap` to avoid collisions with already mapped shared libraries]? Does `malloc` do: `hidden_length,pointer_it_returns` [the classical way] or does it use "arena" allocation. When getting an area from OS, it _must_ be a multiple of the page size (e.g. 4096). But, the arena could be many pages or just one. So, you _can_ overflow up to at least the next page boundary before segfault. Because OP is _reading_, he'll just get garbage values

Comment: @CraigEstey OK. OP requested an answer about Windows, so mmap vs. sbrk are probably not so helpful, but one could assume there are similar features in Windows. I don't particularly mind downvotes, just think the technical discussion could be elevated above "the standard doesn't say anything about it" which is unfortunately a common response to good questions here.

Comment: Ran out of space to say "there are Windows equivalents to `sbrk/mmap` and the principles are the same, anyway". I agree. The LLs are missing the point here. I was going to post an answer similar to yours, but didn't because I felt you had already covered the real reason. I may try later, but consider providing more detail, in simpler terms, so _even_ an LL will get it :-). On SO, sometimes, we _do_ need more pushback against rote LL answers. This question is a good example, and so far, it appears that your answer is the only one that gave the real explanation as to why it _worked_

Comment: References to reliable resources (C draft) of what you're saying are necessary. Not a downvoter.

Comment: @Nuncameesquecideti There is nothing in the C standard about `malloc()` requesting space in larger chunks than it it needs right now. It is merely an obvious optimization to reduce system calls. *Ergo* there is no normative reference to cite about this.

Comment: @Nuncameesquecideti See for example K&R, page 185 http://www.ime.usp.br/~pf/Kernighan-Ritchie/C-Programming-Ebook.pdf

Not all allocators work that way, but the basic principles of allocating a chunk of memory and then splitting it up are the same.

Comment: @Nuncameesquecideti C draft, no. AFAIK, it has no information on how `malloc` is _implemented_, which is crucial to explaining OP's observed behavior. There are a few ways to implement [as I've mentioned above], so the answer should just cover all of them.

Comment: @CraigEstey If you mention something that isn't specified in the standard and is implementation-defined, you should clearly and explicitly say it!

Comment: @Nuncameesquecideti I believe jforberg explained it came from the OS. It's _not_ "implementation defined" as that term is used by the spec [to allow compilers to do things differently]. It is a library/allocator [controlled by POSIX], OS, and architecture issue and _all_ implementations of any sort will allow OP's behavior up to a page boundary, or end of physical memory, or a guard page.